# Firebase Function throws an error com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Response is not valid JSON object

Tags: android, typescript, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to invoke a Firebase https callable function and I get an error in Android Studio saying "com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Response is not valid JSON object"

Here is my code

index.ts file

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()


export { newUserSignUp } from './userCreated'
export { userDeleted } from './userDeleted'

//this is the function that the client is unable to call
exports.sendFeedback = functions.region('asia-east2').https.onCall((data, context) => {
if (!context.auth) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    'unauthenticated', 
    'only authenticated users can add requests'
  )
}
if (data.text.length > 30) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
    'invalid-argument', 
    'request must be no more than 30 characters long'
  )
}
return admin.firestore().collection('Feedback').add({
  Feedback : data.text,
  uid: context.auth.uid
})
})
```

Here is the code in my .kt Activity file in Android Studio

```
private fun sendFeedbackViaCloudFunction() {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    val data = hashMapOf(
        "text" to write_feedback_edit_text.toString(),
        "uid" to FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
    )
    functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
    Timber.i("Calling the cloud function")
    functions
        .getHttpsCallable("sendFeedback")
        .call(data)
        .addOnFailureListener {
            //This is the line thats printing the error log statement
            Timber.i("Failed to invoke the sendFeedback function: $it")
        }
        .continueWith { task ->
            val result = task.result?.data as String
            result
        }
}
```

Error statement threw by Android Studio: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: Response is not valid JSON object.

Comment: You don't need to show transpiled code. I edited it out - it doesn't add any helpful information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok I resolved this, So basically I was getting the "response is not valid JSON object error" repeatedly even after I set a promise to return a valid JSON in my index.ts file.

So apparently if a client is calling a function then the client also needs to specify the [server region](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#client-side_location_selection_for_callable_functions) if the default us-central1 is not the preferred server location. So I had specified the 'asia-east2' as my preference on the server-side but not at the client-side.

Soon as I added the below line at the client side, works perfectly now

```
functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance("asia-east2")
```

Comment: In my case, this along with local build not updating to create index.js with renewed contents was the cause.